# Tiled map editor not launching

Tags: xorg, snap, qt, wayland

I installed [Tiled map editor](https://snapcraft.io/tiled) as a snap application from the software store but when I click on it in the app grid, it does not launch.
When I tried launching via the terminal I get this error:

> $ tiled
>
> Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
> qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland-egl" in ""
> This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
>
> Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

The suggested fix [here](https://github.com/mapeditor/tiled/issues/3503) doesn't work for me. It gives the same error. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding `DISABLE_WAYLAND=1` in the .desktop file to disable wayland for this app. From what I understood, the developer of tiled is aware of the problem and this issue should be fixed in the next release.